# Rails and Chart.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chart.js

I'm trying to get a bar chart in Chart.js to work with the data from a Rails application.  I need to find a way to retrieve the data from the Rails database in the format Chart.js wants.  http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest

Chart.js gives the example of using `data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3]` and `labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"]`

So I can do something like this in my controller

```
@data = [10, 9, 3, 5, 2, 3]
@color_labels = ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"]
@labels = []  
@color_labels.each do |c_label|
    @labels.push(c_label)
end
```

then if I add `<%= @data.to_json.html_safe %>` and `<%= @labels.to_json.html_safe %>` I can pass the data\labels from the controller to the view.

But what I'm really trying to do is to dynamically pull data and labels for the data from the database.

so if I were to try and get the number of books created per month

```
# num of books created per month
@books_count = Book.group_by_month(:created_at).count
```

it would have this output `{Sun, 01 Jul 2018=>12, Wed, 01 Aug 2018=>10, Sat, 01 Sep 2018=>9, Mon, 01 Oct 2018=>4}` I'm not sure how to put this in the correct format of having an array of "book counts per month" and an "array of labels" that have the month names.

in my view

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: <%= @labels.to_json.html_safe %>,
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: <%= @data.to_json.html_safe %>,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: have you tried the chartkick gem? (https://chartkick.com)

Comment: yes, I'm currently using Chartkick as well but wanted to get Chart.js working with Rails too.

Comment: Did my answer solved your problem? If so, accept it by clicking on the tick-mark :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm not sure how to put this in the correct format of having an array
>   of "book counts per month" and an "array of labels" that have the
>   month names.

By looking at `group_by_month`, it is clear that you are using [`groupdate`](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate) gem. Lets use its `format` option to return just ***month names*** as `keys` like below

```
@books_count = Book.group_by_month(:created_at, format: "%b").count
```

which would return the results like this

```
{"Jul" =>12, "Aug" =>10, "Sep" =>9, "Oct" =>4}
```

Now by doing `@books_count.keys` and `@books_count.values` should give the below

```
@books_count.keys
#=> ["Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct"]

@books_count.values
#=> [12, 10, 9, 4]
```

So now you can finally feed them to the respected `labels` and `data` as below

```
labels: <%= @books_count.keys.to_json.html_safe %>
data: <%= @books_count.values.to_json.html_safe %>
```